# Are there laws against International student in UK doxxing others in other country

Tags: united-kingdom

A Chinese international student in the UK doxxing a netizen on Twitter because the netizen have an opposite political standard (don't support PRC) against him. He is going to report this netizen to the Chinese government and may cause that netizens have judicial trouble.

Is it illegal or Violate some rules in the UK?

Comment: This seems to be political and be treated as such. Inform the university and the students there, and see how he likes it.

Answer (score 1):

Doxxing (targeted research and broadcasting of personal information) is not regulated as such. Regulated are separate elements that individual doxxing cases may include: hacking, harassment, extortion, defamation etc.

> He is going to report this netizen to the Chinese government and may cause that netizens have judicial trouble.

So, whether the activity in question is illegal depends solely on whether it includes any illegal elements exampled above. Bringing a person to the attention of justice or law enforcement (whether locally or in any other country) is not illegal by itself.